# Asynchronous AJAX calls (multiple)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I posted this yesterday but i may not have explained my situation well.

I have 3 grids on a page that are built dynamically through JavaScript.

I then have 3 separate JavaScript methods to set a session when a row is clicked in a certain grid.

Once the session is set i would like it to navigate to the next page.

Here is what i have

> OnClick event

```
    $('#clinician-planned').on('click', 'tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
        var ID = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
        var Location = '@Url.Action("SetPASession", "Clinician")';
        AjaxCall(Location, ID);
    });
    $('#clinician-recent').on('click', 'tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
       var ID = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
       var Location = '@Url.Action("SetRDSession", "Clinician")';
       AjaxCall(Location, ID);

    });
    $('#clinician-theatre').on('click', 'tbody>tr>td:not(:last-child):not(:first-child)', function () {
        var ID = $(this).closest("tr").children("td.grid__col--id").find("[name=patient-link]").text().trim();
        var Location = '@Url.Action("SetTESession", "Clinician")';
        AjaxCall(Location, ID);
    });
```

> AJAX Post To Controller

```
        function AjaxCall(Location, ID) {
        alert('1');
             $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: Location,
                dataType: 'text',
                async: false,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                error: function (response) { alert(JSON.stringify(response)); }
             }).done(function (response) {
                 alert('2');
                 location.href = "@Url.Action("Summary", "Patient")" + "/" + ID;
            });
    }
```

> Here are the controller methods

```
    public ActionResult SetPASession()
    {
        Session.Remove("Clinician");
        Session["Clinician"] = "pa";
        return Json(null);
    }
    public ActionResult SetRDSession()
    {
        Session.Remove("Clinician");
        Session["Clinician"] = "rd";
        return Json(null);
    }
    public ActionResult SetTESession()
    {
        Session.Remove("Clinician");
        Session["Clinician"] = "te";
        return Json(null);
    }
```

The problem i have is when the row is clicked "alert('1'); shows instantly, however it seems like it takes a while and waits for all grids to be populated before the 2nd alert appears. I have tried putting async: false, but this doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is next page?

Comment: @MohammadYaseer Hi, it is just further details of the row that is clicked in the previous page. thanks

Comment: so you need to store users selected grids in sessions and replace them with new grids?

Comment: @MohammadYaseer they are just grids with multiple rows in each when i click on a row of selected grid it takes you to a new page, this all works fine, however it will not let me click through until all grids are loaded, i need to be able to click through on each grid as it is loaded. thanks

Comment: async: false, not a good idea you will get warnings..